# Rails getting root_url wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes, url-routing

We developed a site using Rails 3.2.16 and everything was working fine in development and production environments. The problem came when we changed our domain to something like this:

> http://live.mysite.com.es

After changing our domain almost every route works ok except root_url, which redirects to:

> http://www.com.es

I have tried to tell Rails what is my domain name by adding this to 'production.rb':

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: 'live.mysite.com.es'
}
```

But it still gives the same redirection error.

Please let me know if you need more information. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

EDIT:

My routes.rb looks something like this:

```
MySite::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'pages#index'

  resource :dashboard do
    get "events"
    get "products"

    ...

  end

  # More resources here.

end
```

Comment: Can you show your routes.rb please?

Comment: What middleware do you have configured? Because `www.com.es` looks like you force a redirect to a www host and do not take into account that your domain has actually three parts `mysite.com.es` and not just two.

Comment: I do not know quite well what do you mean by middleware, but we are using Nginx to redirect request to rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have been able to find a solution to this problem by adding this to 'production.rb':

```
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {
    host:  'com.es',
    protocol: 'http',
    subdomain: 'live.mysite'
  }
end
```

Thanks everyone!